# JS nested functions

Tags: javascript

I am using nested functions

```
Function mainfunction (callbackfun) {
    //some code + function (score)
    {
        var score = scoreString;
        alert(scoreString);
        callbackFun(score);
    }
}  //--> I return this value to my calling function

mainfunction(function (anystring){
    alert(anystring);  //-> this would return me the value in callbackfun 
});
```

What I want is access that value in `anystring` out like

```
var fetchvalue ;

mainfunction(function (anystring){
    fetchvalue =anystring;  //-> this would return me the value in callbackfun 
});
```

Please guide me if am on the right track .

Comment: Have you tried it? Just a tip: JS is case sensitive, so it should be `function` instead of `Function` and your parameter is named `callbackfun`, not `callbackFun`. With this fixed, this is what your code is doing: http://jsfiddle.net/P3bBP/. Is this what you want?

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to achieve with your code? Edit: ok, after editing the question is visible ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tidying up your code a bit, correcting spelling errors etc..., and watching the output of the `mainfunction` gives you this working script. It is hard to tell if this answers your question, but it does send a variable to a callback function, and then get a return value from that callback.

```
function mainfunction(callbackfun){
  //some code + function (score)
  var scoreString = Math.random()*10000000

  var score = scoreString;
  alert(callbackfun(score));

}; //  --> i return this value to my calling function

mainfunction(function(anystring){
  return anystring;  //-> this would return me the value in callbackfun 
});
```